# what is error can't acquire context from the given item?

Tags: html, vue.js, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am Want to Make line Chart with Chart.js in Vue.js
I want to make this chart based on price and date
I have this Html Code :

```
     <div class="content">
              <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <canvas ref="myChart" width="532.8" height="250"></canvas>
                </div>
                 </div>
                 </section>
        </div>
     </div>
```

And I get This elements From Server :

```
        "sells": [
    {
        "count": "24",
        "price": "966261",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "31",
        "price": "470588",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "8",
        "price": "314518",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "28",
        "price": "576605",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "18",
        "price": "645010",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "26",
        "price": "295104",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "37",
        "price": "303729",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "43",
        "price": "527718",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "35",
        "price": "274219",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "40",
        "price": "471393",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "68",
        "price": "415918",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "3",
        "price": "814208",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "41",
        "price": "839669",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "50",
        "price": "565025",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "21",
        "price": "498100",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "64",
        "price": "458680",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "36",
        "price": "372096",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "61",
        "price": "569098",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "64",
        "price": "519376",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "39",
        "price": "180493",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "39",
        "price": "595028",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "33",
        "price": "55917",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "26",
        "price": "332210",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "34",
        "price": "239726",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "65",
        "price": "984014",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "57",
        "price": "736582",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "57",
        "price": "272335",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "51",
        "price": "235936",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "54",
        "price": "85552",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    },
    {
        "count": "64",
        "price": "222069",
        "date": "۹۹/۰۳/۱۰"
    }
],
```

And I set this Result in `this.sells` and set `date` of `sells` in `this.dataSet` and set `price` in `this.labels`.
my controller Page like this :

```
 import Chart from "chart.js";
 import Axios from  "axios";

  export default{
      data(){
         return {
            labels: [],
            dataSet: []     
       }
     },

  methods:{
      setDate() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.sells.length; i++) {
        this.labels[i] = this.sells[i].date;
        this.dataSet[i] = this.sells[i].price;
    }
   this.createChart();

  },
    createChart() {
       var ctx = this.$refs.myChart


        console.log(ctx);//undefined
        new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: this.labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "2020 Sales",
                    data: this.dataSet,
                    borderColor: "#fff ",
                    borderWidth: "3",
                    hoverBorderColor: "#39ccaa  ",
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#39cccc ",

                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        "#f38b4a",
                        "#56d798",
                        "#ff8397",
                        "#6970d5"
                    ]

                }
            ]
        }
    });
   }

  };




 }
```

I get sells From server and set to `this.sells`

```
    created(){
       Axios.get('/getHomeItem').then(response => {

        if (response.status == 200) {

               this.sells = response.data.sells;

               this.setDate();

           }
        }).catch(error => {
           if (error.response) {
           alert("مشکلی پیش آمده لطفا بعدا تلاش کنید");
        }
    });

 }
```

When i run this Code i get this Error :

> can't acquire context from the given item

And When I Want get `console.log` From `this.$refs.myChart` I get :

> undefined

**I don't know where I went wrong ?**

**Can anyone help?**

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in Vue.js, you can access `this.$refs.uniqueName` only after the instance has been mounted.

Therefore, the code responsible for fetching the data and creating the chart should be moved from lifecycle method [`created`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) to method [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).

```
mounted() {
  Axios.get('/getHomeItem').then(response => {
    ...
    this.sells = response.data.sells;
    this.setDate();
    ...
  });
};
```

**UPDATE**

Additionally to this, you should define an `id` on your `canvas` instead of `ref`.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="532.8" height="250"></canvas>
```

Then you won't need `var ctx = this.$refs.myChart`. The chart can then be created by simply providing the `canvas` `id` instead of the rendering context.

```
new Chart('myChart', {...
```

Comment: It didn't work. I use adminlte. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @Ashkan: I updated my answer with a proposal that hopefully fixes your problem.

Comment: I did it ,but i get null in`console.log(ctx)`

Comment: @Ashkan: If you remove `var ctx = this.$refs.myChart` from your code, then `console.log(ctx)` does not make sense anymore. Do you get any error now?

Comment: I get  `canvas`  using by id and document object  `let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");` and i get `console.log` and get `null`